# TSQL - retrieve results from table A that contains exact data contained in table B

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have TableA (id bigint, name varchar) and TableB (name varchar) that contains the following data:

```
Table A:                        Table B:                      Results:
-------------                  ---------                   ---------------
|  1 | "A"  |                  |  "A"  |                   |  1  |  "A"  |
|  1 | "B"  |                  |  "B"  |                   |  1  |  "B"  |
|  2 | "A"  |                  ---------                   |  4  |  "A"  |
|  3 | "B"  |                                              |  4  |  "B"  |
|  4 | "A"  |                                              ---------------
|  4 | "B"  |
-------------
```

I want to return results from TableA that contains an EXACT match of what's in table B.
Using the 'IN' clause only retrieves back an occurrence.

Also, another example, if TableB has only "A", I want it to return back: 2-"A"

Comment: If I understand you, then you should look at INNER JOIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your question but it is a tricky one as not exactly in line with the relational logic. You are looking for id's for which `SELECT name FROM TableA WHERE id IN ... ORDER BY name;` is identical to `SELECT name FROM B order by name;`.

Can you assume that `A(id,name)` is unique and `B(name)` is unique? Better said, are there constraints like that or can you set them up?

If yes, here is a solution:

#### 1. Get rid of ids in `A` with rows not matching the rows in `B`

```
SELECT id, A.name FROM A WHERE id NOT IN
    (SELECT id FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.name = B.name WHERE B.name IS NULL);
```

#### 2. Count rows per each `id` (this is why the unique constraints are necessary)

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) FROM
    (
        SELECT id, A.name FROM A WHERE id NOT IN
        (SELECT id FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.name = B.name WHERE B.name IS NULL)
    ) t
GROUP BY id;
```

#### 3. Only retain those that match the number of rows of `B`.

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) FROM
    (
        SELECT id, A.name FROM A WHERE id NOT IN
        (SELECT id FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.name = B.name WHERE B.name IS NULL)
    ) t
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM B;
```

Comment: I had implemented #3 myself, tooth and nail.  But unfortunately it fails if TableB contains "A" only.  It returns back IDs of 1, 2, & 4.  The correct result should be those results that only have exactly "A" and nothing else (which should be the ID of 2 from my example).

Comment: And yes, both A(id, name) and B(name) are unique.  Thanks for your post!

Comment: @BRICHARDSON You are right. I see you already have the solution, nevertheless I updated my answer for future reference.

Comment: Great!  This works as well.  Your a stud!  Thanks for taking the time to post.

Answer (score 0):

This works in SQL Server

```
select * from TableA a
where
 (select count(*) from TableB) = (select count(*) from TableA where id = a.id) and
 (select count(*) from TableB) = 
 (
  select count(*) from
  (
   select name from TableA where id = a.id
   intersect
   select name from TableB
  ) as b
 )
```

Comment: Thanks for your post.  This does work if tableB contains "A" & "B"... but if tableB contains "A" only, it brings back result IDs of 1,3,4.  "A" should only result in ID of 2 (because it only has "A" in its data group)

Comment: Your a beast! Thanks!  I would have never thought to go that route.